# How to restore a hidden loadable kernel module from /sys/module and dealing with restoring holders_dir?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, sys

I'm playing with kernel module hiding on Linux Kernel 3.x. I try to hide and recover the module from /sys/module. Everything works fine on Kernel Version 3.0 and 3.2.6. I can load and unload the module and hide and unhide it. When I'm unloading the module on kernel 3.6.6 I get the following error:

rmmod: ERROR: could not open '/sys/module/xxx/holders': No such file or directory
rmmod: ERROR: Module xxx is in use

Does anyone know how I could restore struct kobject *holders_dir of the module so that I am able to unload it without errors?

Here is my code:

```
/* hide from /sys/module */ 
kobject_del(&__this_module.mkobj.kobj);
list_del(&__this_module.mkobj.kobj.entry);

/* add to /sys/module */    
kobject_add(&__this_module.mkobj.kobj,__this_module.mkobj.kobj.parent,"xxx");
```